# Assigning lists to eachother in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Can someone explain me why this python code prints 6 instead of -10?

Why does s2/list2 not change throughout this piece of code?

```
def f(s1,s2):
   s2 = s1
   s1[2] = -7
   s1 = s2
   s2[2] = -10

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
f(list1,list2)
print(list2[2])
```

Comment: Because the first thing you do in f is that you re-bind the name s2 to the list referenced by s1. The latter `s1 = s2` is effectively no-op. Could you please explain a bit more why and what did you expect.

Comment: because python lists are passed by reference. google passing by reference vs passing by value

Comment: You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @IljaEverilä hey that's interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `s2 = s1` you just lost the local reference to `s2` (i.e `list2`). From there on, you're altering `s1` (`list1`), assigning `-7` to `list1[2]` and then `-10`.

You aren't changing `list2` in any way. Use a different name in the assignment to get it to work, `s = s1`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

After the line `s2 = s1` inside the function, the s2 you passed in is no longer relevant inside the function.

That line assigns the value (i.e. list and contents) to the variable s2.